# Python HTTP GET raise Exception after 300 seconds from Docker container

Tags: python, docker, curl, python-requests, pycurl

I'm trying to GET data from an external service using Python from a Docker container.
I need to reach two different endpoints, let's say:

```
endpointA = "https://myhost:1234/resA" # Requests take about 1 minute to complete
endpointB = "https://myhost:1234/resB" # Requests take about 8 minutes to complete
```

I tried to use two different libraries, Requests:

```
import requests
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.get(endpointA, verify=False, headers=headers)
```

and Pycurl:

```
import pycurl

headers = ['Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'Content-Type: application/json']

buffer = BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
c.setopt(c.URL, endpointA)
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, False)
c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYHOST, False)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, headers)
c.perform()
c.close()
```

My code runs without problems from local (both endpointA and endpointB return).

When run inside a Docker container, requests to endpointA work but request to endpointB raise exceptions **after 300 seconds**:

in the case of requests:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 403, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

in the case of pycurl:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 230, in get_data
    c.perform()
pycurl.error: (52, 'Empty reply from server')
```

This only happens from Docker, as from my console everything works fine.

I tried both python:3.6 and python:3.8 Docker images.

I also tried to cURL both endpoints from inside the container and the server replies correctly.

Comment: Since endpoint B takes 8 minutes to run, I'm assuming that it's a very resource heavy process. I think what's happening is that the docker container for endpointB is exceeding 100% CPU or Memory utilization, which will result in non-response to the GET request hence you're error. It's specifically 300 seconds because that's how long it might take to exceed 100% mem. You can check this by running endpoint B, then ssh into the container monitor the usage with `watch htop`. The process will crash if mem usage goes over 100%. You can fix this by allocating more resources to the docker engine.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but no luck here. Process is resource heavy on the server side, my client only waits and gets response (a few kb). Anyway, I tried to allocate more resources but the problem remains and monitoring shows no resource issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify whether docker is terminating the connection by using `nc -l` outside the container and `nc` in the container to connect to the first nc, then leaving them both alone for 10 minutes and then sending something to verify the connection is still up.

To troubleshoot pycurl, see http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/troubleshooting.html#transfer-related-issues.